# Moving ASP.NET site to new Server. The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am moving an existing website to another server, to use as a dev server. Both servers are the exact same configuration. Windows Server 2008, R2. Both have .NET 4.5.0 running.

On the new server, I am getting these kinds of errors:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'mzt_dbtools' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Needless to say, I have verified that the dlls are in the /bin/ directory.

Source error:

```
Line 19:   using System.Collections.Specialized;
Line 20:   using System.IO;
Line 21:   using mzt_dbtools;
Line 22:   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Line 23:   using System.Web.Mail;
```

Detailed compiler output:

> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library
>   /utf8output
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll"
>   /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.dll" /debug-
>   /optimize+ /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror- 
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.10.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.12.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.9.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.4.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.19.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.14.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.8.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.3.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.18.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.7.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.1.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.5.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.11.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.13.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.6.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.16.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.15.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.2.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.17.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\a320bee4\b96e449e\App_Code.utqfm4bn.0.cs"
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.34209
>
> for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> d:\www\ic\App_Code\IC3.cs(21,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'mzt_dbtools' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) d:\www\ic\App_Code\IC3.cs(25,9):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IC_DB' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   d:\www\ic\App_Code\UPSShippingInfo.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'IC_DB' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>   d:\www\ic\App_Code\IC_XMLOrder.cs(3,11): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'IC_DB' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>   d:\www\ic\App_Code\CustomStorageManager.cs(26,7): error CS0246: The
>   type or namespace name 'Radactive' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   d:\www\ic\App_Code\ICOP2.cs(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'IC_DB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>   d:\www\ic\App_Code\MyDynamicLocalizationPlugin.cs(22,7): error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name 'CodeCarvings' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   d:\www\ic\App_Code\MyDynamicLocalizationPlugin.cs(23,7): error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name 'CodeCarvings' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   d:\www\ic\App_Code\MyDynamicLocalizationPlugin.cs(28,7): error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name 'Plugin' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   d:\www\ic\App_Code\MyDynamicLocalizationPlugin.cs(28,15): error
>   CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDynamicLocalizationPlugin' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) d:\www\ic\App_Code\UPSShippingInfo2.cs(7,7): error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name 'IC_DB' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   d:\www\ic\App_Code\IC_JSON.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'IC_DB' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) d:\www\ic\App_Code\IC.cs(21,9):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'mzt_dbtools' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refer ...

Comment: Pls check `mzt_dbtools` reference path is correct.

Comment: mzt_dbtools namespace is in mzt_dbtools, which is in /bin/ directory.

Comment: Yes, but add as reference in your project like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It's a website project. I have never added a reference in visual studio. I have always just uploaded the files via ftp. As the appropriate dll in in the bin directory, it should work.

Comment: Check if mzt_dbtools.dll is under temp folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a320bee4. All the dlls under bin folder should be shadow copied to the temp folder by default and they will be referenced when compiling the page. However, I didn't see that reference in the csc command.

Comment: @mattfei That dll mzt_dbtools.dll, is not in that folder. Can I do something to force it to move there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. It is probably unlikely that someone would encounter the same problem, but here we go.

When I moved the files from one server to the next, I went through the following steps:

```
1. use ftp to download all files from existing server. Downloaded them
to my mac.
2. compressed all files on my mac.
3. uploaded zipped files to the new server, using ftp.
4. unzip the files on the new server
5. apparently, the mac zip program also encrypts the files. So I had to decrypt them.
```

So something went wrong with the zipping or encrypting.

I downloaded the dll's directly from server to server and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check up if the pool application is running in 32 bits or 64 bits.
(in webconfig is the property "enable32BitAppOnWin64" that defines that).

Regards,
Abitar